# Which RAM Module should I pick?

Tags: pc

I got **Asus PRIME B650M-A WIFI II** Motherboard and **Ryzen 5 7600** CPU.
I have already bought a Kingston Fury DDR5 5600MT/s RAM (part number **KF556C40BBA-16**); later on I found it's only XMP (Intel) certified, while I would prefer one that is EXPO (AMD) certified.
Should I return it to buy one with EXPO or keep it?
What will be the consequences if I keep it? (mainly in terms of performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference. I also have XMP RAM on AMD (DDR4) and that works perfectly without XMP, with XMP and even with a minor overclock

Comment: My MB Specs say it supports the following RAM:
4 x DIMM, Max. 128GB, DDR5 6400+(OC)/6200(OC)/6000(OC)/5800(OC)/5600(OC)/ 5400(OC)/ 5200/ 5000/ 4800, ECC and Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory*
Dual Channel Memory Architecture
Supports AMD Extended Profiles for Overclocking (EXPO™)
OptiMem II

Comment: And CPU specs says it supports:
Max Memory Speed: 2x1R DDR5-5200
2x2R DDR5-5200
4x1R DDR5-3600
4x2R DDR5-3600

So while my RAM is 5600MT/s, does it mean it's gonna run at 5200 because of the lack EXPO? Am I right assuming an EXPO Ram runs exactly like a non-EXPO one if no OC is enabled in either cases?

Comment: I don't have any experience with DDR5, but I indeed think it is gonna run 5200 if you do nothing, but if you enable EXPO or XMP (whatever it's called nowadays) it will try to run it on 5600, but if it failes you can still disable it